# In This Case Different Between For Loop and While loop?

Tags: php

```
<?php
while($d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
?>
```

And

```
<?php
for(;$d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);)
?>
```

this both loop are work same but any different between while and for loop?

Comment: 99% of the time the same. There are some instances like not wanting to iterate over an entire collection where while makes more sense. The do while loop make sure you enter the loop logic at least once.

Comment: While in this case both do the same, the first one is much more common and in my opionion more readable for humans. Note that this counts only for this case! A for loop has some more features in its initialisation.

Comment: Intuitive readability.... in this case, you don't need to think about what the while loop is doing, it's intuitive; but you do need to spend time thinking about the for loop before you understand what it's doing, and then spend ages wondering why the original coder wrote it that way, and then spend another 10-years in Strangeways (or Joliet if you're American) for murdering them

Comment: so this case Both r work same

Answer (score 0):

`for` lets you add an initial statement and a statement that's executed every loop. If you remove those, then yes, it should result in an identical behaviour as a while loop. The syntax is:

```
for (initial; comparison; every_loop)
```

If you want to use some sort of iterator-like variable, which changes every loop, it's often easier to use `for`. Do note though that you ALWAYS can recreate a `for`-loop using a `while`-loop. All you need to do is to add the initial statement outside the loop and the "every_loop"-statement at the end of the loop. But because these two are so common, it's often easier to just use `for`. An example of this is:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

...which can be rewritten as...

```
$i = 0; //initial
while($i < 10)
{
    echo $i;
    $i++; //every_loop
}
```